# Windows 7 computer randomly loses IP configuration

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

Title says it all. I recently got a new computer with Windows 7 and it randomly loses its IP configuration. Its IP configuration is all valid and works properly after it boots, but it can randomly lose its IP configuration on average 1-2 times a week.

I have searched various web sites and none of them have a remotely useful answer. I'm using the default (automatic) configurations and never reconfigured the advanced settings for DHCP or IP.

-I'm 100% certain there is no malware causing this.

-All of my internet connections in my home work properly with all of my other computers. (there is no problem with the network otherwise)

-Whenever this occurs, I'm always able to get the internet connection back by right clicking on the connection and "diagnosing" it (in Windows XP, this is called repairing a connection).

---

How do I lock the IP configuration so that a good configuration is never permitted to change? It's annoying getting disconnected randomly.

Comment: If you're using the default DHCP settings what state does it end up in after the settings are lost, disabled altogether or something else?

Comment: What is getting fixed when you repair the connection?  I had this happen with win7 and a laptop and it was actually a hardware defect with the wireless board. I disabled the internal and used a dongle until I was convinced, then ordered the board from HP and today it's good as gold.  (this can also be caused by outdated drivers i found out along the way).

Comment: From the command line, you can run `ipconfig /renew` to renew an exiting lease or get a new IP. You could even set the task to run once a day, before the problem occurs on the 3rd or 4th day. But you should not have this problem in the first place. The computer should renew its lease automatically. You have another problem that has not been identified.

Comment: Is this a wired connection or wireless connection?

Comment: It's a wired connection. I also have my WiFi adapter disabled while using the wired connection so it shouldn't cause conflicts. If this can't be fixed, does anyone know how to configure Windows 7 to automatically repair internet connection while there is no internet access? I would also like to avoid using a manual/static IP address because having an IP address that changes every few days is good protection against DDoS and hack attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it looks like I had 2 logical connections installed to the Ethernet port and it was confusing the operating system. I disabled the extra connections (enable/disable hardware and devices) and it's been working properly ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Set your IP address manually. If you know the range then set the address outside your DHCP range. Don't forget to set DNS as well.

A useful guide on how to do this is here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/?PageSpeed=noscript